# How to use options in QFileDialog.getOpenFileName?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qfiledialog

I would like to use options in the static method QFileDialog.getOpenFileName.

For example i would like to set two options: QFileDialog.ExistingFile and QFileDialog.Detail.

I have already read this text: http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QFileDialog.html?highlight=getopenfilename#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName
but i don't understand how i can use PySide.QtGui.QFileDialog.Options?

```
dir = self.sourceDir
filters = "Text files (*.txt);;Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)"
selected_filter = "Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)"
options = "" # ???
fileObj = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, " File dialog ", dir, filters, selected_filter, options)
```

If i use

```
    options  = QFileDialog.DirectoryOnly
    options |= QFileDialog.List
```

it does not work.

(Windows 7 64 Bit, PyCharm 3.4.1 Pro, Python 3.4.0, PySide 1.2.2)

[image]

Comment: See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#Option-enum for valid options (to translate from c++ to Python replace `::` with `.`)

Comment: @three_pineapples Thank you for your Answer! I try to use your recommendation but it does not work (for example: options = QFileDialog.List).

Comment: That's because `QFileDialog.List` is not part of the `QFileDialog.options` enum. You can only use things in the `QFileDialog.options` enum (read the link carefully again)

Comment: I know what you mean. QFileDialog::List is a QFileDialog::ViewMode. I would like to set the QFileDialog::FileMode and QFileDialog::ViewMode too. How can i do this? OK, but i try also QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly - it does not work. I need a small example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this if you are using the static functions with a native file-dialog.

The native file-dialogs do not have the same API as the Qt file-dialog, so you can only set the properties that are available via the static function arguments - which means the caption, title, working-directory, filters, and [options](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#Option-enum).

The static functions more or less match the various [file modes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#FileMode-enum):

```
AnyFile = getSaveFileName
ExistingFile = getOpenFileName
Directory = getExistingDirectory
ExistingFiles = getOpenFileNames
```

When using the static functions, the `ShowDirsOnly` option will only work with `getExistingDirectory`. But on Windows, that will open the native "Browse For Folder" dialog (unless you set the `DontUseNativeDialog` option), and so the `ShowDirsOnly` option would be redundant.

There is currently no way to set the `ViewMode` for a native-dialog when using the static functions, and the same goes for all the other APIs that are specific to `QFileDialog`.

Long-story short: if you want more control over the file-dialog, use the built-in Qt one - that's what it's there for.